# addListenerForSingleValueEvent does not retrieve anything from Firebase (Kotlin)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I've never used Kotlin before so please bear with me if the question sounds stupid. I've been stuck for three days now and none of the answers on stackoverflow works. I've been following this tutorial on how to retrieve data from Firebase and I've followed every single instructions correctly but nothing came out in the logcat console. I'm supposed to see the DataSnapshot there. If you can just throw some ideas on what went wrong I'd be happy to try anything to fix this issue.

Here's my code:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                p0.children.forEach {
                    Log.d("FirebaseActivity", it.toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
```

My database structure:

```
{"Users" : {
    "jcYZToEGUzdzoLflYzfeHTV244p1" : {
        "Name" : "John Doe",
        "Age"  : "25"
        }
    }
}
```

My original JSON file is way more lengthy and has more nodes. Initially I thought this was the problem because I read somewhere Firebase doesn't encourage having too many layers which is why I thought testing it on a simplified version might work. Unfortunately, that doesn't fix it either.

Comment: First thing is to stop ignoring possible errors and implement `onCancelled`. For example: `override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) { throw error.toException(); }`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen after I tried log.d at multiple places, I noticed that it never went into onDataChange or onCancelled. Do you have any idea what might cause this? No one else has this issue. I've tried invalidate cache and rebuild project but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: That sounds like your device isn't connected to the server, or internet. I sometimes have that on an emulator after I close/reopen my laptop. Did you check the network connection?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my device is definitely connected to the internet since user have to sign in when they use the app. The sign in part works fine with Firebase, but somehow retrieving data has been a headache for me. I have no clue what went wrong.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I added a simplified version of my database structure. Stack overflow doesn't allow me to attach picture unfortunately.

Comment: If neither `onDataChange` nor `onCancelled` are triggered, most likely you are not connected to the internet.

Comment: @AlexMamo the app is definitely connected to the internet since user have to login before proceeding to the next page. The login part works just fine with Firebase. The only issue is the data retrieving part. Is there a way for me to specifically check if this part of the code doesn't connect to the internet?

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you placing those lines of code?

Comment: @AlexMamo Basically I'm supposed to make a school app for parents so they can check on their children's exam result and attendance for that current week. It's a 5 marks assignment so I kept it really simple. After logging in, user will pick either attendance button or exam result button. Clicking the button will bring user to attendance/exam result page. The code is placed on those pages since there is where we need to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: Bu in which place, in onCreate()?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, in onCreate()

Comment: I don't know if there are other people with the same issue here but if you ever come across this thread, I want to let you know I did not found a solution and I had to rebuild my app from scratch again for it to work.